# Maximizing Log Likelihood Estimation in Python

Tags: python, mle

Currently I am writing my thesis about the liquidity of green bonds. I am trying to compute the LOT measure based on Lesmond et al. (1999) and Chen et al. (2007). Therefore, I need to maximize the following log likelihood function

```
L(a 1,j,a 2,j, β j,1, β j,2,σ j|R j,t,∆Index)
```

in python (a screenshot is appended for better readability):

[image: Log Likelihood Function]

```
Φ i,j
```

denotes the cumulative distribution function for each bond-year evaluated at

```
L(a i,j− β j,1D j,t∗ ∆R f,t− β j,2D j,t∗ ∆Index t)/σ j
```

So far, I tried to apply the following code, but unfortunately received wrong estimates yet:

```
 import numpy as np 
 from scipy.optimize import minimize
 from scipy.stats import norm

  x = np.random.rand(200,7)
  y = np.random.rand(200,1)

  def negative_loglikehood(params,x):

     alpha_1 = params[0] 
     alpha_2 = params[1]
     beta_1 = params[2]
     beta_2 = params[4]

     rjt = x[:,0]
     djt = x[:,1]
     index = x[:,2]
     rft = x[:,3]

     term_0 = np.sum(np.log(1/(2*np.pi*sigma)**0.5))

     term_1 = np.sum( (1/ (2*sigma**2) ) * (np.sum(rjt+alpha_1-beta_1*djt*rft) - beta_2*djt*index )**2)

     term_2 = np.sum(np.log(1/(2*np.pi*sigma)**0.5))

     term_3 = np.sum( (1/ (2*sigma**2) ) * (np.sum(rjt+alpha_2-beta_1*djt*rft) - beta_2 *djt*index )**2)

     term_4 = np.sum(
            np.log(
              norm.cdf( y, loc=(alpha_1 - beta_1*djt*rft - beta_2*djt*index)/sigma, scale=sigma)
            - norm.cdf(y, loc=(alpha_1 - beta_1*djt*rft - beta_2*djt*index)/sigma, scale=sigma)
            ))

     LL1 = (term_0 - term_1 + term_2 - term_3 + term_4)
     return(LL1)
 
guess = [1,1,1,1,1]
results = minimize(negative_loglikehood, guess,args =(x), method = 'Nelder-Mead', options={'disp': True})
print(results.x)
```

I am not sure of the implementation of my code is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your formula when compared to the analytic expression you have provided:

in `term_2 = np.sum(np.log(1/(2*np.pi*sigma)**0.5))` sigma should be squared
-> `term_2 = np.sum(np.log(1/(2*np.pi*sigma**2)**0.5))`.

This is also the case for term_0, change term_0 to `term_0 = np.sum(np.log(1/(2*np.pi*sigma**2)**0.5))`

You also seem to be minimizing the **positive** log-likelihood. This is the opposite of what you want to do. To minimize the negative LL change

```
return(LL1)
```

to

```
return(-LL1)
```

You also do not correctly evaluate the cdfs in term_4. In Lesmond 1999 it states that Φi,j are the cdfs of a standard normal distribution evaluated at (,−1Duration,∗Δ−2Duration,∗ΔS&P Index)/. However, what you have programmed is to evaluate a non-standard normal distribution with mean (,−1Duration,∗Δ−2Duration,∗ΔS&P Index)/ and variance sigma^2 at some value y. To evaluate the correct cdf, you need to change term_4 to

```
term_4 = np.sum(
            np.log(
              norm.cdf((alpha_2 - beta_1*djt*rft - beta_2*djt*index)/sigma, loc = 0, scale = 1)
            - norm.cdf((alpha_1 - beta_1*djt*rft - beta_2*djt*index)/sigma, loc = 0, scale = 1)
            ))
```

, where in the first term alpha_2 is used and in the second one alpha_1 as stated in Chen 2007.

In Chen 2007 it also states that α1 j, α2 j, βj, and σj are solved by maximizing the likelihood. You have yet not included σj in your optimization ( i guess you have defined it as a scalar somewhere?). You need to add σj to the params argument so that is also optimized for in the minimization.

Additionally, the sums do not use the correct indices:
n Chen 2007 it says: ∑1 (region 1) represents the negative nonzero measured returns, ∑2 (region 2) represents the positive nonzero measured returns, and ∑0 (region 0) represents the zero measured returns. However, you use rjt for all terms.

You need to subset rjt (and all other variables in the sum that depend on t) according to the indices in the sum before each term. In the sums with ∑1, you need to retrieve the indices j for negative nonzero return regions, for ∑2 the indices j for the positive nonzero measured return regions and so on.

You can try to subset the terms as follows:

```
term_0 = np.sum(np.log(1/(2*np.pi*sigma**2)**0.5))

term_1 = np.sum( (1/ (2*sigma**2) ) * (np.sum(rjt[rjt < 0] +alpha_1-beta_1*djt[rjt < 0]*rft[rjt < 0]) - beta_2*djt[rjt < 0]*index[rjt < 0] )**2)

term_2 = np.sum(np.log(1/(2*np.pi*sigma**2)**0.5))

term_3 = np.sum( (1/ (2*sigma**2) ) * (np.sum(rjt[rjt > 0]+alpha_2-beta_1*djt[rjt > 0]*rft[rjt > 0]) - beta_2 *djt[rjt > 0]*index )**2)

term_4 = np.sum(
          np.log(
            norm.cdf( (alpha_2 - beta_1*djt[rjt == 0]*rft[rjt == 0] - beta_2*djt[rjt == 0]*index[rjt == 0])/sigma, loc=0, scale=1)
          - norm.cdf( (alpha_1 - beta_1*djt[rjt == 0]*rft[rjt == 0] - beta_2*djt[rjt == 0]*index[rjt == 0])/sigma, loc=0, scale=1)
          ))
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast and helpful reply. I recognized the mistakes and edited the original post. 

However, after running the code I receive the following error: 

RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  np.log(

Moreover, for the correct implementation, I am still unsure which variables to bet set for y. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: I think your x variables in this model are the variables ```rft``` and duration ```djt```, which is the daily change in the 10-year risk-free interest rate (according to the Chen 2007 paper, right after equation 1) and the duration of the risky bond respectively, from which you want to predict the y variable ```rjt``` which is unobserved “true” bond return for bond j and day t that investors would bid given zero liquidity costs (according to the Chen 2007 paper).

Comment: I guess you have probably a dataset where x and y are collected over some time period? You have also passed x and y correctly to the minimization. The variable y you have, however, is not necessary, as the true y variables are already contained in what you have denoted as ```x``` ( which contains rft, rjt and djt).

Your np.log error must occur somewhere in term_0, term_2 or term_4 since the other terms feature no np.log. I would suggest you insert a print statement before computing each term so you can catch which term throws the error.

Comment: I think there is also another mistake in term_4. In the first norm.cdf you should use alpha_2 - at least this is how Phi2 is specified right after equation 4 in Chen 2007 - this could possibly be the issue for the np.log error , since you're subtracting exactly the same terms from each other which results in zero evidently. 
Also it says in the Chen 2007 paper, that where Φi,j represents the cumulative distribution function for each bond-year evaluated at  (,−1Duration,∗Δ−2Duration,∗ΔS&P Index)/ . However, you do not evaluate the CDF at this term but pass it

Comment: ... as the mean of the normal distribution. In Lesmond 1999 you can find the information, that Φi,j is a standard normal distribution.
I will update my answer on how to change this correctly.

Comment: Thank you again for your fruitful contribution. I edited my code and changed it in the original post. Now the estimation functions correctly and gives back reasonable values for the parameters. However, they largely depend on the values to be set for the initial guess, in such a way, that the estimation does not give back consistent results. Moreover, I am wondering if the sums for the different regions and Rj,t in the Chen 2007 paper are correctly integrated, especially if you consider that Rj,t is dependend on alpha_1 and alpha_2, and negative, zero or positive values respectively.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on this issue?

Comment: In Chen 2007 it says: ∑1  (region 1) represents the negative nonzero measured returns, ∑2 (region 2) represents the positive nonzero measured returns, and ∑0 (region 0) represents the zero measured returns. However, you use rjt for all terms. You need to subset rjt according to the meaning of the sums.

Comment: I also don't think you should update the code in your answer as I provide the corrections. Rather add a section "Update" at the end of your question, where you present the current version of your code and the problems associated with that code. Otherwise the question and answer do not really fit together.

Comment: I updated the answer with how to subset the terms in the sums, let me know whether this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks again for your help, which is really appreciated. I rechanged the initial post back to the first version. 
Also, I implemented your code and basically it seems to work. However, the problem with inconsistent results for the parameters remains as they largely depend on the initial guess values to bet set. My suggestion would be that the local minimization method does not have a good fit and that maybe an algorithm for a global minimum/maximum should be applied?

Comment: Yes indeed, the Nelder-Mead optimizer can get stuck in local minima. One solution would be to run the minimization with different starting values. After obtaining the optimal parameters for each starting value, you can evaluate the negative log likelihood for each set of optimal parameters and choose the set of parameters where the negative log likelihood is minimal. You could also play around with the other optimizers in the ```minimize``` function and check whether other optimizers give you better and more robust results.

Comment: In the documentation for the minimization function it also states about the Nelder-Mead method: "However, if numerical computation of derivative can be trusted, other algorithms using the first and/or second derivatives information might be preferred for their better performance in general.". so you could resort to ```L-BFGS-B ``` or ```Powell ```. I think, however, that if there exist local minima in your optimization space and you do not have a closed form solution, that every algorithm can get stuck in a local minimum.